# Add check constraint related to other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

My table structure is as below

```
User  |Group   |IsActive   |GoSequence
--------------------------------------
1     |max     |1          |4
2     |jun     |0          |0
3     |cle     |1          |1
4     |trk     |1          |2
5     |wdr     |0          |6

User=int, Group=varchar(3), IsActive=bit, GoSequence=int
```

I want to add a constraint to this table where only if `IsActive=1`, `GoSequence` value can be change.

If `IsActive=0`, `GoSequence` stays 0.

```
ALTER TABLE [pbr_TeamPel] ADD CONSTRAINT [CHK_pbr_TeamPel_GoSeq]
    CHECK ~

/*If IsActive = 0 then GoSequence=0, else 
if IsActive = 1, GoSequence can be change to other int*/
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the simplest way of expressing that is that either GoSequence must be 0 or IsActive must be 1.

So your constraint could look like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [pbr_TeamPel] ADD CONSTRAINT [CHK_pbr_TeamPel_GoSeq]
    CHECK(GoSequence=0 Or IsActive=1)
```

Comment: Simple but powerful! Thanks a lot :)